# distinguishing between user file/data file and system/program file in java

Tags: java, file

Is there any method in java to distinguish whether a file/folder is a user's file/folder?
whether the file/folder is system/program file?
One can consider a simple text file created by user and text file containing log created by operating system. How can one distinguish between the two?
Who created the file this information could be helpful. It would be great help with an example code in Java.

Comment: You can do this in a standard way ... in Java 7. If you have the option of upgrading to it then feel free to check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html, in particular the `getOwner()` method and the `getAttribute()` variants.

Comment: @Perception:I tried this but using getOwner() does not helps it returns same administrator name for both kind of files

Comment: Works for me on Mac 10.7.2. What platform are you on?

Comment: @Perception: window xp, the getOwner() returns the adiministrator/machine name for both kind of files

Comment: How did you create the files in Windows XP? Have you checked the file attributes to verify the actual owner? Windows 'ownership' attributes are more convoluted than *nix.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 7 you can accomplish this with the new `Files` API:

```
final Path filePath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("some.file.path");
final UserPrincipal owner = Files.getOwner(path);
System.out.printf("File %s is owned by %s\n", path, owner.getName());
```